# min-height with calc and position fixed not working on mobile

Tags: ios, css

I have a mobile menu with `position:fixed` and min-height of `calc(100vh - 48px)`. Top is set to 48px. In the mobile menu I have a wrapper set to `height:100%` and `overflow:auto`. I tried setting it to `min-height: 100%` but it doesn't work. When the content gets taller, the content inside is hidden and there is no scroll. I have set overflow to auto and then tried scroll on the mobile menu but nothing works. What may cause the problem?

```html
.mobile-nav__menu {
      width: 100vw;
      min-height: calc(100vh - 48px);
      position: fixed;
      top: 48px;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition-property: all;
      -o-transition-property: all;
      transition-property: all;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
           -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
              transition-duration: 0.5s;
      z-index: 21;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .mobile-nav__menu-wrapper {
      min-height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height property on window resize javascript event something like that;

```
var onresize = function() {
   height = document.body.clientHeight;
}
window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using percentage instead of absolute px values.
For example,if u want a header of height 10px on a screen that is 1000px tall, type in "1%" instead of "10px".
This will help the header to adapt to different screen sizes.
Also try adding `background-size:cover` OR `background-size:100%` in the css class.